# Getting Database Access Level In C#

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, authentication

I have a sql 2005 database with access controlled by a couple of AD groups. There is a group to provide read only access and one with full access.

Is there an easy way of asking SQL server what level of access a user currently has, i would like my app to pop up with a message telling the user if they only have read only access.

Cheers
Luke

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is similar to what you ask but for the Create Table permission, should be easy to follow and apply needed changes: [How can I detect whether I have CREATE TABLE permission?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5748591/how-can-i-detect-whether-i-have-create-table-permission)

Comment: Its not really ideal, but i think your way seems the best

Answer (score 0):

If you use `sp_helpuser` it will return a table of users with their current roles.