# What is the meaning of a specific part of an SQL statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server

We keep the changes of the sql server tables as script in TFS. When i get a change script from SMSS, there is some line at the bottom of the script. Which is;

```
select 
  Has_Perms_By_Name(N'dbo.MyTableName', 'Object', 'ALTER') as ALT_Per, 
  Has_Perms_By_Name(N'dbo.MyTableName', 'Object', 'VIEW DEFINITION') as View_def_Per,
  Has_Perms_By_Name(N'dbo.MyTableName', 'Object', 'CONTROL') as Contr_Per
```

What is the purpose of this line? Does it matter if i ommit this line from my script files?

Comment: related: [How can I detect whether I have CREATE TABLE permission?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5748591/how-can-i-detect-whether-i-have-create-table-permission)

Answer (score 2):

The query reports the current user's permissions against the target object using a built-in function [`HAS_PERMS_BY_NAME`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189802.aspx).

It's not required for version control, so you could omit it.

Comment: Okay, it reports the user permission against the target objects BUT why is it included in Change Script?

Comment: @ozdogan - it might be to do with your SSMS scripting options. How exactly are you generating your scripts, and in which version of SSMS?

Comment: SMSS -> Tools -> Options -> Designers -> Auto generate change script

Comment: @ozdogan - I can't replicate on SQL 2008 R2 SP2 or SQL 2012 express; does this happen on every change or just certain kinds of changes?

Comment: yes it happens on every change. Please go to the setting which i said before, check the option. Then in design mode of any table make some changes then click the Save button, to save the changes. At that point a window automatically appears with the related change script.

Comment: @ozdogan - those are the steps I followed when attempting to replicate. By inference this is an issue specific to whatever version of SSMS you're running. I don't see it in the versions I have available to test

Answer (score 1):

The function `Has_Perms_By_Name(...)` evaluates the permission of the current user on a table.

The syntax is:

```
HAS_PERMS_BY_NAME ( securable , securable_class , permission  
[ , sub-securable ] [ , sub-securable_class ] )
```

whereas

> securable: Is the name of the securable. If the securable is the server itself, this value should be set to NULL. securable is a scalar expression of type sysname. There is no default.
>
> securable_class: Is the name of the class of securable against which the permission is tested. securable_class is a scalar expression of type nvarchar(60).
>
> permission: A nonnull scalar expression of type sysname that represents the permission name to be checked. There is no default. The permission name ANY is a wildcard.
>
> sub-securable: An optional scalar expression of type sysname that represents the name of the securable sub-entity against which the permission is tested. The default is NULL.
>
> sub-securable_class: An optional scalar expression of type nvarchar(60) that represent the class of securable subentity against which the permission is tested. The default is NULL.

The return type of the function is an int and defines, if the current user has the specified permissions.

Also, take at look at this [link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189802.aspx)